# find match, print first occurrence and continue until the end of the file - awk

Tags: awk

I have a pretty large file from which I'd like to extract only the first line of those containing my match and then continuing doing that until the end of the file. Example of input and desired output below

**Input**

```
C,4,2,5,6,8,9,5
C,4,5,4,5,4,43,6
S,4,23,567,2,4,5
S,23,4,7,78,8,9,6
S,3,5,67,8,54,56
S,4,8,9,54,3,4,52
E,2,3,213,5,8,44
E,5,7,9,67,89,33
E,54,526,54,43,53
S,9,8,9,7,9,32,4
S,5,6,4,5,67,87,88
S,4,23,5,8,5,7,3
E,4,6,4,8,9,32,23
E,43,7,1,78,9,8,65
```

**Output**

```
S,4,23,567,2,4,5
S,9,8,9,7,9,32,4
```

The match in my lines is S, which usually comes after a line that starts with either E or C. What I'm struggling with is to tell awk to print only the first line after those with E or C. Another way would be to print the first of the bunch of lines containing S. Any idea??

Answer (score 4):

does this one-liner help?

```
awk '/^S/&&!i{print;i=!i}!/^S/{i=!i}' file
```

or more "readable":

```
awk -v p=1 '/^S/&&p{print;p=0}!/^S/{p=1}' file
```

Comment: This does not check whether the `S` line is preceded by a `C` or `E` line. I guess this question has some bio-informatics, genetics background. Please have in mind that such a bug can have severe consequences. ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl `Another way would be to print the first of the bunch of lines containing S.` I thought this would solve OP's problem too

Comment: Oh, I see, the question was a bit unclear. At the end I feel slightly more comfortable when awk is used instead of sed...

Comment: From Kent answers it looks like we are all going to die very soon...just kidding, this is not bio at all! For some reason the first code line doesn't work with my real dataset but the second one does perfectly. And true this is not testing whether the S line is preceded by C or E but it doesn't matter. Many thanks Kent, I'd ask for a brief explanation if you're brave enough!

Comment: @eikonal `p` variable is a flag, read `printIt?` default was set by `1(true)`. if it found `S` line and `printIt=true`, print it, then set `printIt=0(false)`, the `printIt` was set to `1(true)` again, if a line not matching `S` was read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`, like this:

```
sed -rn '/^(E|C)/{:a;n;/^S/!ba;p}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a multi liner to enter in a file (e.g. u.awk)

```
/^[CE]/ {ON=1; next}
/^S/ {if (ON) print}
{ON=0}
```

then run : "awk -f u.awk inputdatafile"

Comment: Basically your same idea with a bit more pith: `awk '/^[CE]/ {on=1; next} on{print; on=0}'`

Comment: uppercase variable names are not recommended in `awk`

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^[CE]/{p=1} /^S/&&p{p=0;print}' file

S,4,23,567,2,4,5
S,9,8,9,7,9,32,4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/^S/{if (!f) print; f=1; next} {print; f=0}' file 
C,4,2,5,6,8,9,5
C,4,5,4,5,4,43,6
S,4,23,567,2,4,5
E,2,3,213,5,8,44
E,5,7,9,67,89,33
E,54,526,54,43,53
S,9,8,9,7,9,32,4
E,4,6,4,8,9,32,23
E,43,7,1,78,9,8,65
```